# Trying to build a 'frontend' for Raspberry Pi python games

Tags: python

Story for the poorly worded question, but not sure where to start.

I was thinking of creating a frontend for the python games that come bundled with Raspbian. It would consist of screen shots, title and small description of each game, but not allow the user to exit the frontend to the desktop. The player can exit the games, at which point they will be returned to the frontend

My initial thoughts were to use pygame, but this may tax the pi if it has to run the games as well. Can anyone suggest anything better or if something similar already exists for the pi?

Thanks
tom

Comment: Welcome to rpi on the stackexchange! I'm afraid you won't get very good answers on this question - it is quite broad and abstract. On this site, you usually get the best answers when you have a specific problem and you have tried something and it doesn't really work as you expect. Questions about "what framework would be best for this or that type of thing" tend to be a lot harder and less interesting to answer. Please try to implement your idea, and ask new questions when you run into trouble.

Comment: Hi Bex, thanks for your response. Do you know of somewhere it is appropriate to ask the kind of general question that i asked?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could modify the Python Games program. You can find it in the 'Python Games' folder at /home/$USER. It uses either uses Tkinter or Pygame